# Invalid attepmt to spread non-interable instance inside my Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, core-js

I am getting the following error:

```
new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a
```

My code:

```
(() => {
    let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]')];

    const settings = {
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.01
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((imageEntites) => {
        imageEntites.forEach((image) => {
            if (image.isIntersecting) {
                observer.unobserve(image.target);
                image.target.src = image.target.dataset.src;
                image.target.onload = () =>
                    image.target.classList.add('loaded');
            }
        });
    }, settings);

    images.forEach((image) => observer.observe(image));
})();
```

I am using the latest core-js and babel.

Wondering what Is wrong with my code because it works when I run it in development mode.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList` which is non-iterable instance. Convert it to an array: `let images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]'))`

Comment: Using the spread syntax should work fine on a NodeList on recent browsers. This is probably caused by a setting/preset in Babel.